# Passing value from menu in python

Tags: python-3.x

Looking for a shortcut, if there is one to be had.  Below is part of the code I'm using with much more still to be added in tonight as I finish off the rest of the menu selections.

Is there a shorter way of setting a value other than by going to a separate function and setting then the value and calling the main function that performs the action.  Can it be done directly from menu.add line?

```
    menubar = Menu(root)
    a = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    b = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    c = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    d = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    e = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    a.insert_cascade(0, label = 'Option 1', menu=b)
    b.add('checkbutton', label = 'Choice 1', command = self.f1)
    b.add('checkbutton', label = 'Choice 2', command = self.f2)
    a.insert_cascade(1, label = 'Option 2', menu=c)
    c.add('checkbutton', label = 'Choice 1', command = self.g3)
    c.add('checkbutton', label = 'Choice 2', command = self.g4)
    a.insert_cascade(2, label = 'Option 3', menu=d)
    d.add('checkbutton', label = 'Choice 1', command = self.h1)
    d.add('checkbutton', label = 'Choice 2', command = self.h2)
    d.add('checkbutton', label = 'Choice 3', command = self.h5)
    a.insert_cascade(3, label = 'Option 4', menu=e)
    e.add('checkbutton', label = 'Choice 1', command = self.i1)
    e.add('checkbutton', label = 'Choice 2', command = self.i2)
    e.add('checkbutton', label = 'Choice 3', command = self.i5)
    menubar.add_cascade(label = 'Routines', menu=a)

def f1(self):
    self.sttype = 1
    self.routine()

def f2(self):
    self.sttype = 2
    self.routine()

def g3(self):
    self.sttype = 3
    self.routine()

def g4(self):
    self.sttype = 4
    self.routine()

def h1(self):
    self.sttype = 1
    self.routine()

def h2(self):
    self.sttype = 2
    self.routine()

def h5(self):
    self.sttype = 5
    self.routine()

def i1(self):
    self.sttype = 1
    self.routine()

def i2(self):
    self.sttype = 2
    self.routine()

def i5(self):
    self.sttype = 5
    self.routine()
```

Comment: Your example doesn't make much sense with checkbuttons - since they're all setting distinct values on a single variable, shouldn't they be radiobuttons?  Either way, these two types of menu items won't work right unless you pass a `variable=` option - that's how they know what state they should display.  Once you give them all distinct `variable=`s (checkbuttons), or a shared `variable=` and distinct `onvalue=`s (radiobuttons), you can have all their `command=`s point to the same routine - which can look at the variable(s) to know what to do.

Comment: This is a mapping program and when I click on a choice it displays the data associated with that choice, or it removes it...still have to work on the removal side but I know it does display the data.  Everything is grouped together depending on who it belongs to, aka, restaurants/stores/hotels etc are grouped together(Option) with each individual business(Choice) being displayed.  The data file has the distinct marker in the file so it can tracked/displayed.  I was kinda rushing when I typed everything up but it still gives the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: The idea is that you can have more than one selection in each option, more than one business ,in each grouping that you want to display.